# sql / postgresql - counting value increase within month range

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have the table below named `tbl`,

```
| id | json     | date                |
| -- | -------- | ------------------- |
| 1  | {"id":1} | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 1  | {"id":1} | 2021-09-02 00:00:00 |
| 1  | {"id":1} | 2021-09-03 00:00:00 |
| 3  | {"id":3} | 2021-09-03 00:00:00 |
| 4  | {"id":4} | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 |
| 4  | {"id":4} | 2021-09-02 00:00:00 |
| 5  | {"id":5} | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 5  | {"id":5} | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 |
| 5  | {"id":5} | 2021-09-02 00:00:00 |
| 5  | {"id":5} | 2021-09-01 00:00:00 |
| 5  | {"id":5} | 2021-09-03 00:00:00 |
| 5  | {"id":5} | 2021-09-04 00:00:00 |
```

Here, I need to get the value increase in occurrences between January and September. If the id did not have an entry in *both* January and September, then we ignore it since we only want to include changes between months. For our purposes we don't need to show the ids with a negative change.

I am looking for an output as follows,

```
| id | json     | change |
| -- | -------- | ------ |
| 1  | {"id":1} | 1      |
| 5  | {"id":5} | 4      |
```

Below is a query that I currently have, but unclear how to count monthly values...

```
with id as (
    select json_array_elements(json->'id')
    from tbl
),
date as (
    select date
    from tbl
)
select *
from id, date;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a two-step solution: First count the number of occurrences for each ID for January and September, then subtract and filter out the rows you don't want. I skipped the json since it just repeats the information in the ID.

```sql
WITH counts AS (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE date_trunc('month', date) = '2021-09-01 00:00:00') as sept_occurrences, 
    count(*) FILTER (WHERE date_trunc('month', date) = '2021-01-01 00:00:00') as jan_occurrences 
  FROM tbl 
  GROUP BY id
) 
SELECT id, sept_occurrences - jan_occurrences as change
FROM counts
WHERE sept_occurrences > 0
AND jan_occurrences > 0;

 id | change
----+--------
  5 |      4
  1 |      1
```